# conversion fields kibana and logstash

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I try to convert a field "tmp_reponse" in integer in the file "conf" with logstash as follows :

```
mutate {
convert => {"TMP_REPONSE" => "integer"}
}
```

,but on Kibana it shows me that he is still string. I do not understand how I can make a convertion to use my fields "tmp_response" to use it like as a metric fields on kibana

[image]
thank you help me please and if there is anyone who can explain to me how I can master the metrics on Kibana and use fields as being of metrics fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mutate{} will change the type of the field in logstash.  If you added a stdout{} output stanza, you would see that it's an integer at that point.

How elasticsearch treats it is another problem entirely.  Elasticsearch usually sets the type of a field based on the first input received, so if you sent documents in before you added the mutate to your logstash config, they would have been strings and the elasticsearch index will always consider that field to be a string.

The type may also have been defined in an elasticsearch template or mapping.

The good news is that your mutate will probably set the type when a new index is created.  If you're using daily indexes (the default in logstash), you can just wait a day.  Or you can delete the index (losing any data so far) and let a new one be created.  Or you could rebuild the index.

Good luck.